# Adding tabs again to tab fragment activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have an app which has navigation type fixed tabs + swipe. And I have created two tabs using two fragments, fragment 1 and fragment 2. It's working fine. Now again I need to create 3 tabs for the fragment 1. How can this be acheived??

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Flights","My Bookings" };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

// Adding Tabs
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
        .setTabListener(this));
}

/**
* on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
* */
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // on changing the page
    // make respected tab selected
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}
});
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// on tab selected
// show respected fragment view
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

}
```

This is my TabsPagerAdapter class:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
            return new Flight();
    case 1:
            return new Hotel();


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

}
```

This is my mainactivity.xml file

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Then there are two fragment activities Flight and Hotel in my app. Now Again I need to add tabs to the fragment activity flight. How can this be acheived?? Can someone please help me out...

**Edit**: This is an image from net. This is what I exactly want..

[image]

Comment: you need to add a another tab seperately?

Comment: fragment flight and fragment hotel are two tabs in the main activity. Now I need to add 3 tabs to fragment flight. that is in main activity there are two tabs. 1) flight 2)hotel. Upon clicking flight tab, flight fragment is displayed. Now In the flight fragment, I need to display 3 tabs below it. These three tabs are 1) round trip 2)one way and 3) multiple city..These 3 three tabs needs to be displayed only inside the flight tab. And should become visible only after clicking flight tab..

Comment: Sorry it's not fragment hotel. it is fragment my bookings...

Comment: you can done it using deprecated Tab host with the help of Action bar sherlock.`http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-nested-fragment-tabs-tutorial/` check out that link.just make it as example and done it in Action bar tabs.Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your layout of flight fragment must be changed to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
 >

<TabHost

    android:id="@+id/TabHost01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >

            <anylayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 >
            </anylayout>

            <anylayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:dividerHeight="3dp" >


            <anylayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

          </anylayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>

 </LinearLayout>
```

and in onCreatView :

```
mTabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);

mTabHost.setup();

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_1")
                .setIndicator("View1_Child1")
                .setContent(R.id.tab_1));

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_2")
                .setIndicator("View2_Child2")
                .setContent(R.id.tab_2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another Fragment Class Like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (index) {
case 0:
        return new Flight();
case 1:
        return new Hotel();
case 2:
       return new Thirdfragment();
}
return null;


 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 3;
  }
```

And Dont forget to add third tab in  MainActivity class 
       private String[] tabs = { "Flights","My Bookings",ThirdFragment };